GitHub Packages: Manage access to package from Actions using API?
I'm trying to configure access so that I can consume a package hosted in GitHub Packages from another repo than the repo that created it. Ideally I'd like to use the GITHUB_TOKEN and not have any system user that I need to administrate. To achieve this I found that using the "Manage Actions access" section on the Package-settings page, I'm able to grant access to the other repo. However I have a lot of packages and potential repos that will consume these packages so I'd like to programmatically configure this somehow but I can't seem to find any APIs in the GitHub REST API that allows for this. Can someone point me in the right direction?


You can generate a Personal Access Token with the read:packages scope in the repo that publishes packages.
Use this PAT in the other repositories to authenticate and access the packages. You will have to create a secret PAT in each repo that needs this access.
steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Configure npm for GitHub Packages
    run: |
      echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.PAT }}" > ~/.npmrc

  - name: Install Dependencies
    run: npm install


Thanks for your input but this is what I would like to avoid doing

You can not add repos to the package access list via API. You may have to automate Web actions to add these repos. However,. you can add secrets to many repos via an API. Is your objection about creating a PAT token?

Yea I'd like to avoid having to tie it to a personal account or create service accounts. Especially when the functionality is right there :)

Makes sense. The only other anutomation option is to use GitHub App private key. You can generate a short lived token in your workflow to access the packages. You can also add this private key to all repos that need access using GitHub CLI.  Let me know if you need more info
